# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміну Risk Exposure

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту "PMBOK та PM ISO українською". Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

Варіанти:

- Вплив Ризиків
- Схильність до Ризиків

Визначення терміну Risk Exposure [там](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Risk_Exposure) таке:

> **Risk Exposure.** An aggregate measure of the potential impact of all risks at any given point in time in a project, program, or portfolio.

> Для обчислення risk exposure, аналітки використовують таке рівняння:
>
> ```
> (імовірність настання ризику) X (сума втрат у випадку настання ризику) = risk exposure
> ```

Comment: "Піддаваний до ризиків" або "Піддавання ризикам"

Answer (score 1):

Пропоную *потенціал ризику.*

Тут може виникнути питання - чому потенціалом варто вважати саме ймовірність помножену на втрати. Для того, щоб точніше вказати які саме втрати ми маємо на увазі під потенціалом можна використовувати

- *реальний потенціал ризику*
- *абсолютний потенціал ризику*

Де `РПР = АПР * (ймовірність настання)`. І вважати *потенціал ризику* синонімом до *реальний потенціал ризику*.